# iText7 PdfFormField.SetValue removes leading blanks

Tags: itext7, pdf-form

I am filling a pdf form with **iText7**. If I set the value of a form field (`PdfFormField.SetValue()`) with leading blanks (ie `"        some text"`), the blanks are not visible in the final pdf. Is there any way to keep the leading blanks in the final pdf?

```java
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
foreach (var fld in form.GetFormFields())
{
    PdfFormField field = form.GetField(fld.Key);
    field.SetValue("         some text");
}
```

Comment: Try using a non-breaking space (U+00a0) as first space character.

Comment: the non-breaking space didn't work but I found u200c does.  Thanks for the suggestion.